# Issues connecting to Node JS websocket using 'connection' keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, blockchain

I am setting up a peer to peer server for a blockchain project which leverages the Node JS ws websocket client. For whatever reason, the arrow function in my server.on(...) call does not execute. When I change the keyword to 'listen' however, the function executes. Please help :P.

p2p-server.js:

```js
const Websocket = require('ws');
const P2P_PORT = process.env.P2P_PORT || 5001;
const peers = process.env.peers ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];

// HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5003 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001,ws://localhost:5002 npm run dev

// HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev



class P2pServer {
    constructor (Blockchain) {
        this.blockchain = Blockchain;
        this.sockets = [];
    }

    listen() {
        const server = new Websocket.Server({ port: P2P_PORT });
        // server.on('connection', socket => this.connectSocket(socket));
        server.on('connection', socket => this.connectSocket(socket));

        // this.connectToPeers();

        console.log(`Listening for peer-to-peer connections on: ${P2P_PORT}`);
       
    }

    // connectToPeers() {
    //     peers.forEach(peer => {
    //         const socket = new Websocket(peer);
            
    //         socket.on('open', () => this.connectSocket(socket));
            
    //     });
    // }

    connectSocket(socket) {
        
        this.sockets.push(socket);
        console.log('Socket connected.')
    }

    
}

module.exports = P2pServer;
```

index.js:

```js
// REST API
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const BlockChain = require('../blockchain');
const P2pServer = require('./p2p-server');

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
const bc = new BlockChain();
const p2pServer = new P2pServer(bc)

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/blocks', (req, res) => {
    res.json(bc.chain);
});

app.post('/mine', (req, res) => {
    const block = bc.addBlock(req.body.data);
    console.log(`New block added: ${block.toString()}`);

    res.redirect('/blocks');
})

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${HTTP_PORT}`));
p2pServer.listen();
```

Comment: `require('./p2p-server').default;` why the `.default` ?

Comment: Must have accidentally added it. removed, but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

simple syntax error messed me up in line 3.

This...

```js
const peers = process.env.peers ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];
```

should have been this...

```js
const peers = process.env.PEERS ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];
```

Comment: both are same :-|